# canvas keyPress movement - broken

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

My keyPress movement seems to be broken, if I press arr.up/down twice then it gets broken and I can't move the element back. And the element doesn't even stop when I stop holding the arr.up/down, why?

```
rocket = new Image();
x = 50;
y = 185;
score = 0;
velY = 0;
speed = 2;

y += velY;
ctx.drawImage(rocket, x, y);

    if(e.keyCode == 38) {
    if(velY < speed) {
        velY --;
    }
}

if(e.keyCode == 40) {
    if(velY < speed) {
        velY ++;
    }
}
```

Preview: http://game.stranger.tk/

Comment: Check your `<` comparison operators ... one of them probably should be `>`.

Answer (score 0):

I would have edited your code however your game via your link isn't working :(. I hope this code example I have provided helps you out.

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/w1z2c1cq/

javascript

```
var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

var rocket = function()
{
    this.Sprite = new Image();
  this.Sprite.src = "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS9zafp1ezdR2lSAxTdjZYe_nPhe6VeKKmAuK-GzWQCSs395WkzNA";
    this.XPos = 100;
  this.YPos = 100;
}

var player = new rocket();

setInterval(function()
{
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,400,400);
    ctx.drawImage(player.Sprite, player.XPos, player.YPos);
}, 3);


window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
        // Left key
    if(e.keyCode === 37) {
        player.XPos -= 5;
    }
    // Right key
    if(e.keyCode === 39) {
        player.XPos += 5;
    }
    // Up key
    if(e.keyCode === 38) {
        player.YPos -= 5;
    }
    // Down key
    if(e.keyCode === 40) {
        player.YPos += 5;
    }
});
```

Also in your code you are checking this same if statement for up and down `if(velY < speed)`

try

```
// Up
if(e.keyCode == 38) {
    if(velY < speed) {
        velY --;
    }
}

// Down
if(e.keyCode == 40) {
    if(velY > -speed) {
        velY ++;
    }
}
```